# Why does back-propagation on different devices yield different results

Tags: pytorch

I ran GPT-J on different devices, i.e., A: NVIDIA-A100, B: NVIDIA-A40, C: NVIDIA-A800, and yielded different results. I have set identical random seed and confirmed the neural networks are initiated with the same weight and the data loaders retrieve data in the same order. However, the output in forward propagation of C is different from A and B. After I set `torch.backends.cuda.matmul.allow_tf32=False`, the outputs of C in forward propagation is identical with A and B but the gradient in back propagation is still different. Is there any reason that may lead to this phenomenon?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.